# Prove/disprove questions on isomorphism and embedding between order types

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, order-theory

> About the notations: Let $\lambda, q, z, \omega$ be the order types of the reals, rationals, integers and natural numbers respectively. The sign $=$ means there's isomorphism and $\le$ means there's embedding between the two order types and $\omega^* = \overline {(\mathbb N, \ge)}$. $\overline {(A,R)}$ is the order type of $(A,R)$.
>
> Prove/disprove the following:
>
> 1. $\overline {([0,1),\le)}=1+\lambda$
> 2. $\omega+\omega^*=z$
> 3. $\omega+\omega\le z$
> 4. $z\cdot z \le q$
> 5. $(1+\lambda)\cdot 2=1+\lambda $

**(1)** True: I can define an isomorphic function $f:[0,1) \to \{0\} \cup (0,1)$ like so: $\phi(x)= \begin{cases}& 1 &,x=0 \\ 
                       &\arctan(x)&,x\in(0,1)\end{cases}$

Now am I supposed to show that $\phi $ is 1-1, onto and preserve the order or is it obvious since arctan is an elementary function ?

**(2)** False, since the LHS has a maximal and minimal elements but $z$ does not.

**(3)** True, define $f:\mathbb N +\mathbb N \to \mathbb Z$ by $\begin{cases}(n,0)\to n+1\\ (n,1)\to -n\end{cases}$

But I'm not sure about that since: $f(\mathbb N +\mathbb N)=\{1,2,3...\}+\{0,-1,-2...  \} $

**(4)** Define: $f:\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Q$ by: $(a,b)\to \frac a b$ where $a\neq b\in \mathbb Z$ and are primes. Or a more simple function which should be isomorphic too: $(a,0)\to a$ where $a\in \mathbb Z$.

**(5)** I don't think it's true since $(1+\lambda)\cdot 2=1+\lambda +1 + \lambda =1+\lambda\cdot 2\neq 1+\lambda$

Comment: What do you mean by $\overline A$? (Like $\overline{[0,1)}$ or $\overline{(\mathbb N,\ge)}$.) Is it order type of the set $A$? How is the inequality of order types defined?

Comment: @MartinSleziak we defined the overline to mean that it's an order type, like for example: $\omega=\overline{(\mathbb N,\le)}$ or $\overline {[0,1)}=\overline {([0,1),\le)}$

Comment: You should probably include the relevant definitions in your post (or give a link to some material that contains definition). Apart from $\overline A$, other undefined notions, which are not that common, are $a\le b$, $a\cdot b$ (is it lexicographic ordering?) and also $a+b$; but the last one probably can be guessed.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I did add a description for $\le$, the $a \cdot b$ is Cartesian product $A\times B$ and addition I'm not really sure myself, the instructor solved something similar to 3 in the same manner only it was to $\mathbb Q$ instead of $\mathbb Z$. It's most likely to indicate {0,1,...}+{0',1'...}.

Comment: What do you mean by "$A\times B$ and addition"? If you want to talk about *order type*, then you need to have some *order relation" on the set $A\times B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1)** I am confused by what you wrote as a solution for (1). Do you really want a bijection between $\{0\}\cup(0,1)$ and $[0,1)$? If yes, then the bijection is the identity map $f(x)=x$. But maybe you want to find (order preserving) bijection between $\{-\infty\}\cup\mathbb R$ and $[0,1)$.

**(3)** I do not think that the map you wrote is order preserving.

Moreover, if $f$ is any embedding $f \colon (\mathbb N,\le) \to (\mathbb Z,\le)$, then $f$ must be unbounded (from above). (You can try to prove this by induction.) If you want an embedding $g$ of $\mathbb N+\mathbb N=\{(n,0),(n,1); n\in\mathbb N\}$ into $\mathbb Z$, then $g(n,0)\le g(0,1)$ for each $n$. So $n\mapsto g(n,0)$ must be an embedding of $\mathbb N$ into $\mathbb Z$, which is bounded from above. (Informally, you want to put two copies of $\mathbb N$ into $\mathbb Z$ in a such way that one of them follows the other. If you choose the second one, then the first copy of $\mathbb N$ must be bounded by the first element of the second copy.)

Another possible argument: In $\mathbb N+\mathbb N$ there are two elements, which do not have an [immediate predecessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_relation). If you take a subset of $\mathbb Z$, you can have at most one such element. (It will be the smallest element, if the set is bounded from below.)

**(4)** I assume that $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ is given the [lexicographic order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). This is the same as replacing each $a\in\mathbb Z$ by a copy of $\mathbb Z$ (and keeping the ordering between these copies).

To build an embedding of $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ maybe you could first think about this: Can you embed $\mathbb Z$ in $(0,1)\cap\mathbb Q$? Can you embed $\mathbb Z$ into $(a,a+1)\cap\mathbb Q$ for $a\in\mathbb Z$? Do you get what you want by combining such embeddings for all $a\in\mathbb Z$?

What you suggested is not a function, because it is only defined for some pairs of integers, not for all pairs of integers. Moreover, $(3,2)\le(5,7)$ in the lexicographic order, but your function gives $f(3,2)=3/2 > 5/7 = f(5,7)$, so it is not order preserving.

**(5)** You are using $a\cdot 2=a+a$ without explaining why this holds. This is not true for lexicographic ordering. (For example $\omega\cdot 2$ means that you replace each element in $\mathbb N$ by two elements. The resulting set is isomorphic to $\mathbb N$.) So maybe you are using some different ordering on the product? (Lexicographic order, where the second coordinate is more important, like in [multiplication of ordinals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Multiplication)?)

Even if you have an ordering on the product such that distributive law works in the way you used it, you should still explain why $\lambda\cdot2\ne\lambda$ to finish your proof.

Note: Just in the case the OP changes some of proofs/solutions in his pots: All what I wrote above is related to the [revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/820640/4) of the question at the time I've made this post.

Comment: For 1, I think I did a function from $[0,1) \to \{0\}\cup \mathbb R$. Why there's the minus infinity in $\{-\infty\}\cup\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: For 5, how come it isn't true for any order type ? isn't $\omega\cdot 2 \neq \omega$ ? And I didn't know how to explain this property $\lambda\cdot2\ne\lambda$.

Comment: Some explanation that $2\cdot\omega=\omega$ is given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145706/operations-on-ordinal-numbers/145850#145850). You should notice that the post I linked to uses antilexicographic order. So for lexicographic order you get $2\omega=\omega$. Probably *the most important thing* you should do is to tell us how you define $a\cdot b$. Is it lexicographic order? Is it some different ordering or the product?

Comment: Your first comment is rather unclear to me. You have $\{0\}\cup\mathbb R=\mathbb R$, so this would be just the set of real numbers. In your post you wrote: *"I can define ... function $f:[0,1) \to \{0\} \cup (0,1)$"* The set $\{0\} \cup (0,1)$ is the same as $[0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the option to help via chat, I couldn't at the time I saw it. Yes, I checked, it is the lexicographic order. Would it be enough as an explanation for why $\lambda\cdot 2 \ge \lambda$ to say the LHS has a limiting element while the RHS doesn't ?

Comment: For 1 can I choose $(0,1)$ as the representative for $\lambda$ ? and then the function would simply be the identity function ? I still don't understand why you adviced to use $\{-\infty\}\cup\mathbb R$.

Comment: (4) I got another function that is order preserving: $f(a,b)\to a^3 b^2$ so if $(a,b)\ge (a',b')$ then $a^3 b^2\ge a'^3 b'^2$.

Comment: The function you suggested is not order preserving (w.r.t lexicographic order). Anyway, it might be better to continue this discussion [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15962855#15962855), so that there are not too many comment here.